# How to get multiple columns into text from sharepoint site?

Tags: powerbi, dax

I know how you can go to the fieldcolumnsastext and then use the drop down to select what columns want to be text. After that though say there is another column added in from sharepoint that isn't text when in Power BI where can I go again to make the column text?

Answer (score 0):

You go to the Transform and editor in the Source click on gear icon and then select the new columns.

Comment: Can you explain further? Possible screenshots please.